# marble-touch offline map viewer fails to start

Tags: kde, qt

Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity, marble-touch 4:4.13.3-0ubuntu0.1. It doesn't start:

```
$ marble-touch 
qrc:/main.qml:13:1: Type MarbleWindow unavailable 
qrc:/MarbleWindow.qml:11:1: module "com.nokia.meego" is not installed
```

Seems like the bug '14419 marble-touch does not open a window' was fixed:

https://bugs.mageia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14419

But I can't find a packaged version with the fix (and how to build is unclear). In Vivid there is a marble-touch package with a weird version '4:14.12.3' which gives the same error.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Marble Touch shouldn't be packaged on the Desktop - the target device for this application is the Nokia N9 cellphone :-) .
Please use Marble or Marble-Qt instead - on the terminal it should be accessible either via "marble" (KDE version) or "marble-qt" (Qt-Only version without KDE dependencies).

Comment: Well, it is packaged for amd64 in the Ubuntu repo. And if it runs, it will run on the Ubuntu phone too (that's what I am actually trying to get).

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's feasible to get Marble Touch to run on the Ubuntu phone since Marble Touch requires some MeeGo stuff. But if you want to get Marble running on the Ubuntu Phone just join us on #marble or the marble mailing list. Right now there is a chance that during the Summer there will be an Android port created - The code for that could probably be used for a Ubuntu Phone version as well :-) .